# Methods to show the convergence/divergence of following series:

Tags: real-analysis

This is the series I have a question about: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln n)^2 }{2^{\ln n}}$.
The root and ratio test are both inconclusive, so I tried Raabe's test of convergence. It seems too difficult to find the limit because the term $\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}$ becomes huge (also when applying de l'Hopital's rule). Could someone help me please? Are there any rules/methods on how to approach proving the convergence of series? How can they be applied on this given series?

Comment: Use Cauchy-Condensation test...

Answer (score 0):

$a^{\ln n} = e^{\ln a \ln n} =n^{\ln a}$
so the sum
$\sum (\ln n)^b/a^{\ln n}$
 converges if 
$\ln a > 1$,
diverges if
$\ln a < 1$,
and depends on the value of $b$
if $\ln a=1$.

In this case,
$\ln a =\ln 2 < 1$
so the sum diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=\sum(\ln n)^2/2^{\ln n}=\sum(\ln n)^2/n^{\ln 2}$

Now $s_n=\sum \frac{2^n .(\ln 2^n)^2}{2^{n\ln 2}}=\sum 2^{n(1-\ln 2)}n^2(\ln 2)^2$

Since  $1-\ln 2>0$, So $s_n$ diverges $\Rightarrow$ $a_n$ diverges

Answer (score 0):

There is this useful Cauchy condensation test, implying that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^na_{2^n}$ is convergent, usable if $a_n$ is nonincreasing sequence of nonnegative numbers. Since $2^{ln n}$ is faster than $(ln$ $n)^2$ one can assume that this sequence is nonincreasing ( as it is nonincreasing for $n$ large enough ), and of course $a_n$ are nonnegative, so one can use this test. It follows that our sum converges iff sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n(ln(2^n))^2/2^{ln(2^n)}$ = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n(nln2)^2/2^{nln2}$ = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2(ln2)^2/2^{n(ln2 - 1)}$ = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2(ln2)^22^{n(1-ln2)}$ converges, but this one obviously diverges, as $ln2$ $< 1$.